# How to check if Request object contains a given parameter

Tags: java, spring

I have a REST endpoint /v1/abc.
It is a POST method.
In the request body i send an object Test which looks as below.

```
Class Test {
   Boolean flag = null;
   String name = null;
}
```

I invoke the endpoint using swagger.

In the request body, i set below.

```
{
 "name" : "hello"
}
```

If you notice, I am not sending flag at all.
In my API, i want to test if the request object has flag or not. If not present, i throw an exception.

Can you tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: You can get that using the HttpServletRequest object. request.getParameter("name_of_your_parameter"); if the result is null. Then you know it is not present.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a simple `POST` method like this one:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/v1/abc")
public void addAbc(@RequestBody Test test) {
    //code
}
```

So you could just check `test.getFlag() != null` and thereafter raise an exception or not.

As an alternative you could add `@Valid` to your method parameter to enable [JSR 303 bean validation](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-mvc/spring-bean-validation/) and make use of `@NotNull` on your `flag` field.

Little remark: the keyword `class` in your example has to be written in lowercase.

Comment: I tried both the above. The 'not null' check worked when i had my request like this     `{flag=null, name = 'abc'}` but not when it was not present in the request body at all.

Comment: What means "but not"? What is happening? If `flag` is not in the request body, the `Boolean` variable will be null. Please augment your question with code you tried and the error messages in case of "but not".